# How to upload the file to File Net using NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, express, filenet

I have a requirement to upload the image pdf file/files to [IBM File Net](https://www.ibm.com/products/filenet-content-manager) using Express.JS! How to do it?

I'm a new bee for File Net, even I'm not able to find sufficient docs for the same.

Any help will much be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are out of look as FileNet does not come with suitable APIs out-of-the box.

tl;dr: You have the following options:

1. Develop a custom service
2. Install and use the optional CMIS API
3. Install and use the optional GraphQL API (only if you are on FileNet version >= 5.5.4)

You may ask if installing and configuring the [IBM ECM CMIS for Enterprise Content Management](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEUEX_3.0.7/com.ibm.developingeuc.doc/cmidv026.htm) would be an option. That would allow you to use [CmisJS](https://github.com/agea/CmisJS).

With FileNet 5.5.4 they introduced an optional [Content Services GraphQL API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGLW6_5.5.0/com.ibm.p8.relnotes.doc/wn_cpe_dev554.htm)

As an alternative, you or somebody else with FileNet experience needs to develop a custom REST/Web-Service for uploading files.

Answer (score 0):

IBM filenet offers a SOAP interface. Bij importing the WSDL you can easily use this from any programming language. Start with SOAPUI. Import the wsdl and experiment.
C# example
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/filenet-p8-platform/5.2.0?topic=examples-document-creation-mtom-content-example